# Counting documents in a collection

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

How can I count documents in a collection using Mongoosejs?

I've tried this but I just get undefined in the console:

```
Doc.find({},function(err,docs) {
  console.log(docs.count);
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`docs.length` would get the number of elements in the `docs` array of your code, but it's much more efficient to use [`Model.count`](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.count) for this:

```js
Doc.count({}, function(err, count) {
    console.log(count);
});
```